# Inserting an invalid ActiveRecord date to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

MySQL allows the value of `0000-00-00` for `date` fields, however `ActiveRecord` treats an assignment to a `Date` value with that string as being `nil`.

I have a legacy application that relies on that exact field content for the notion of "Never", so if the customer last payment date is `0000-00-00` it acknowledges as being "Never" paid.

Is there a way I can override `ActiveRecord` (correct) validation for this `date` field and write this value to the database without getting my hands (too) dirty?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this slightly easier and it should achieve the same result without executing the method for every attribute in the model

```
class CustomerInfo < BillingDatabase
  belongs_to :customer

  def lastpaid
    value = read_attribute(:lastpaid)
    value.blank? ? "0000-00-00" : value
  end
end
```

You could of course refactor the code to call read_attribute twice and do the lastpaid method as a one-liner. It's a matter of style/minute performance differences really.

```
def lastpaid
  read_attribute(:lastpaid).blank? "0000-00-00" : read_attribute(:lastpaid)
end
```

Comment: This seems to be for ancient Rails, Rails 2 maybe?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this on a Rails 3.0.3 project and monkey patched the following which allows you to assign '0000-00-00' to a model date field.  This value will be carried through to the mysql database column on insert/update.

```
  class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column
    def self.string_to_date_with_zero_support(string)
      return string if string == '0000-00-00'
      string_to_date_without_zero_support(string)
    end

    class << self
      alias_method_chain(:string_to_date, :zero_support)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate answering my own questions, but after a little more research about AR code itself, I came up with this solution:

```
class CustomerInfo < BillingDatabase
  belongs_to :customer

  alias_method :old_read_attribute, :read_attribute

  def read_attribute(attr_name)
    if attr_name == "lastpaid" and old_read_attribute(attr_name).blank?
      "0000-00-00"
    else
      old_read_attribute(attr_name)
    end
  end
end
```

I will leave this question open in case someone has a better approach or want to comment on possible flaws.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the default value on the database to be "0000-00-00" using a proper sql alter table alter column ...; statement.